# How do i fill part of a shape's color in PaintCode?

Tags: paintcode

So i have this vector in for a rating system in PaintCode

[image]

I would like to be able to fill the colors partially. Like this:

[image]

Can this be accomplished in PaintCode?

Comment: @Mr.T _“People who say it cannot be done should not interrupt those who are doing it.”_

Comment: I just woke up at 3am in the morning just too see the notification on my mobile and it is your comment. You are absolutely right. I always add "as far as I know" before I say anything. I wonder I missed it this time. I apologize for such a negative comment. And I really appreciate your effort in the below answer. @iMartin

Comment: @Mr.T That’s OK, sorry for waking you up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible.

[image: Animated Rating]

How did I do that:

1. Made the stars as a **clipping** shape for a simple rectangle in the background.
2. Created a numeric variable *Stars* that is supposed to be from 0 to 5. This will be a **parameter** of the canvas:

   ```
   - (void)drawRatingWithStars: (CGFloat)stars;
   ```
3. Created an **expression** variable *Width* like `100 / 5 * stars`, where 100 is the width of all 5 stars.
4. Attached this *Width* variable to the **width** of the rectangle.

---

**Edit:** The GIF animation was exported from PaintCode using a helper fraction variable *Animation*, which I animated from 0 to 1 (in GIF export settings). I then changed *Stars* to be an expression with this content `5 - 10 * abs(animation - 0.5)`. That maps numbers in `0..1` to `0..5..0`.

Comment: Hey Martin, could you please tell me in more detail on how to achieve this task? I am trying to do this but I couldn't succeed.

Comment: After adding the width variable to rectangle, how do I animate them like you did above ?

Comment: @iMartin, if you can provide the PaintCode file this will be perfect. How on earth did you do that?

Comment: @iMartin never mind, i think i found the documentation on clipping! thanks!

Comment: I posted link to this PaintCode file here https://twitter.com/tricertops/status/675206123041984512, but it’s on my Dropbox, so I cannot guarantee it will last there forever.

Comment: I updated the .pcvd file to show the GIF export. Variable names are a bit different.